# Answering boolean question without knowing "Who" answer

Tags: hash, integrity, data-privacy

Can cryptography solve this problem?

Two people are chatting, Mr. X and Ms Y. They give each other a CRC16 hash of someone's name initials and salt a random number at the end (suffix).

> Ms Y: "I love someone with the initials {53d4}".

> Mr X: "Are that person's initials {da17}?"

```
{CRC16} -> Original String
{53d4} -> A7777
{da17} -> X123
```

This means, Ms. Y loves someone with initials name `A` and Mr. X thought it was someone with initials name `X`.

How can they both know answer of Mr.X's question **WITHOUT** knowing the guessed person's initials? So the expectation is to know only the boolean answer, YES or NO without knowing who the person is, no matter who is it. I mean, X shouldn't know who is it and Y shouldn't know who the person of X thought.

Note: You can modify dialogue or totally change dialogue as long as it answers the `how` question.